# Finding any element in symmetric min max heap

Tags: find, heap, complexity-theory

I am looking to find (and update) a single element in a symmetric min-max heap. In this project I need to be able to update ANY element in logarithmic time. I have no idea how this would work though.

Finding an element in a min-heap or a max-heap is linear in runtime. According to everything I find online, a symmetric min-max heap can find the min and max elements in constant time but nothing even mentions finding another element.

The only thing I can think of is searching the entire heap but that gives linear runtime.